# How to use translate method in rails with an text which is been binding by Angularjs model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have an issue when i use translate method in Rails for dynamic text is created by Angular binding

```
%div =t '{{button.label}}'
```

button.label is a text value which stored in database, When i write code as above, the 't' method in Rails understands the translation key is `{{button.label}}`

How can i make the translation key becomes an text which is stored in database
I recognize that t method will execute before Angular binds data from database. That is reason why t can not create key is text in db